# How to add text to a span element in a for loop using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I'm trying to validate a form with an array and a loop. I created empty span elements in each required field. Then, in JavaScript I set up this:

```
var name = document.querySelector('#Name').value,
  firstLastName = document.querySelector('#firstLastName').value,
  secondLastName = document.querySelector('#secondLastName').value,
  username = document.querySelector('#username').value,
  dateBirth = document.querySelector('#dateBirth').value,
  email = document.querySelector('#email').value,
  gender = document.querySelector('#gender').value,
  password = document.querySelector('#password ').value,
  passwordConfirmation = document.querySelector('#passwordConfirmation').value,
  span = document.getElementsByTagName("span"),
  personalData = [name, firstLastName, secondLastName, username, dateBirth, email, gender, password, passwordConfirmation],
  arrayLength = personalData.length;



  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    if (personalData[i]== '') {
      var message = '*Required'
      span[i].innerHTML = message; /* THIS PART IS NOT WORKING */

    }else {
      var message = ''
      span[i].innerHTML = message; /* THIS PART IS NOT WORKING */
    }
  }
```

Any idea what the problem is? I'm new on this.

Here's the HTML code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Regsitrar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body class="container-fluid">


    <header class="row">
      <a href="#"><img class="col-md-2" src="./img/cenfotec-logo.png" alt="Music Logo" width="167px" height="80px"/></a>
      <h1 class="col-md-6">Welcome!</h1>
    </header>

    <section id="form" class="row">

      <form class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="registrationForm" name="RegistrationForm">
        <h2>Registration</h2>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td >
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="Name"> <br>
                <span id="errorName" class="span"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" id="firstLastName">
                <span id="errorFirstLastName" class="span"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Second Last Name"  id="secondLastName">
                <span id="errorSecondLastName" class="span"></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <label for="dateBirth">Date of Birth: </label>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
              <input type="date" id="dateBirth">
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
              <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address"  id="email">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
              <select id="gender">
                <option value="">--Select Gender--</option>
                <option value="male">Male</option>
                <option value="female">Female</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
              <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
              <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="passwordConfirmation">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
              <input type="button" value="Create Account" id="btnRegistration">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
    </section>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/logicIU.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show your html.

Comment: Can you do a console.log on span or see you get any console errors ?

Comment: where OP gone ???

Comment: It would be better if you could show the html also.

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty wired to me that getElementsByTagName not working on span element.

For working code you can try this

```
<span class='.span'>Data1</span>
<span class='.span'>Data2</span>

var x = document.getElementsByClassName(".span");
x[1].innerHTML = 'works';
```

Here JsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/s4cdLrcg/1/

If you are getting undefined error on span elements probably you loading script before the dom elements finishs its loading.

**Try to Load your script at bottom of your html page then it will work.**

Comment: That worked. However, as soon as I put the "i" variable instead of [1] I get an error from the console. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined(…)

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the snippet below which confirms you don't have any issues with your script.

You should place the scripts after the *html elements* same as the below snippet.

*Note*: I have put the scripts inside the `validate()` function so that, when you type something and click the button, you can see the validation message removed.

But this snippet will work without the function as you did above.

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="Name" /> <span></span>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="firstLastName" /> <span></span>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="secondLastName" /> <span></span>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="username" /> <span></span>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Validate" onclick="validate()" />

<script>
  
function validate() {
  var name = document.querySelector('#Name').value,
  firstLastName = document.querySelector('#firstLastName').value,
  secondLastName = document.querySelector('#secondLastName').value,
  username = document.querySelector('#username').value,
  //dateBirth = document.querySelector('#dateBirth').value,
  //email = document.querySelector('#email').value,
  //gender = document.querySelector('#gender').value,
  //password = document.querySelector('#password ').value,
  //passwordConfirmation = document.querySelector('#passwordConfirmation').value,
  span = document.getElementsByTagName("span"),
  personalData = [name, firstLastName, secondLastName, username],  //, dateBirth, email, gender, password, passwordConfirmation],
  arrayLength = personalData.length;


  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    var message = '';
    if (personalData[i] == '') {
      message = '*Required';
    }
    
    span[i].innerHTML = message; /* THIS PART IS NOT WORKING */
  }
}
  
  
  validate();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your code inside  function (i.e)

```
<input type="button" value="Validate" onclick="validate()" />
function validate(){
//Your code
}
```

Comment: I didn't copy and paste that part of my JS file. However, I created a variable and add an event listener to it. There is no problem with that. Thanks anyway!